# Как с помощью скрипта заменить маску телефона в полe input в зависимости от выбранной страны в поле select

Tags: jquery

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть следующая конструкция:

```js
$("#phone_1_field").mask("+7(999) 999-9999");
```

```css
div {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

select,
input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.maskedinput@1.4.1/src/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select>
    <option value="">-- Выберите Вашу страну --</option>
    <option value="11">Армения</option>
    <option value="20">Беларусь</option>
    <option value="176">Российская Федерация</option>
    <option value="220">Украина</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div><input placeholder="Телефон" type="text"  id="phone_1_field" class="required"> </div>
```

Сейчас если кликнуть в поле Телефон `#phone_1_field` в нем маска телефона для России, начинается на +7, как сделать с помощью скрипта, что если пользователь выбрал например Украину `option value="220"`, то подключалась другая функция с маской телефона начинающейся на +380

**Благодарю за ответ!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var maskMap = {
  11: "+374(000) 000-000",
  20: "+375(00) 000-00-00",
  176: "+7(000) 000-0000",
  220: "+38(000) 000-0000",
  12: "+995(000) 000-000"

}

/*на случай если в коде используются цифры 9 */
$.mask.definitions['9'] = false;
$.mask.definitions['0'] = "[0-9]";

$("#phone_1_field").mask("+7(000) 000-0000");

$('select').change(function(){
  var phoneMask  = maskMap[this.value];
  $("#phone_1_field").mask(phoneMask);
  $("#phone_1_field").val('').focus();
})
```

```css
div {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

select,
input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.maskedinput@1.4.1/src/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select>
    <option value="">-- Выберите Вашу страну --</option>
    <option value="11">Армения</option>
    <option value="20">Беларусь</option>
    <option value="176">Российская Федерация</option>
    <option value="220">Украина</option>
    <option value="12">Грузия</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div><input placeholder="Телефон" type="text"  id="phone_1_field" class="required"> </div>
```

Comment: Хороший вариант (+)

Comment: @De.Minov , взаимно. Я тоже сначала думал маску в `value` запихать, но судя по вопросу там какие-то цифры нужные стоят.

Comment: @zhurof Спасибо за ответ и рабочее решение! К сожалению у меня нет возможности вносить изменения  в  `<option value="....">` этот список генерирует компонент одной из CMS. Возможно ли привязать заранее созданные маски к значениям в `<option value="....">` ?

Comment: Самым простым способом выразить зависимость между `value` и маской телефона, на мой взгляд, будет объект. Изменил ответ. По идее должно подойти

Comment: @zhurof Огромное спасибо, то что нужно!!! Немного не по теме вопроса, но все же спрошу нельзя ли дополнить скрипт и в поле `input id="phone_1_field"` принудительно ставить каретку после кода сразу после символа `(` даже если пользователь во время ввода случайно кликнет вот сюда к примеру `+7(___) _|__-____` У меня есть скрипт маски который это умеет, но немного замороченный со сложными функциями вызова, которые не могу объединить с вашим решением. Придется остаться на скрипте маски из вопроса, но был признателен еще за помощь с курсором. Или надо задать другой вопрос?

Comment: Вот тут вроде есть решение этой проблемы https://webstool.ru/jquery.maskedinput.html#fix_center_click

Comment: @zhurof Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить скрипт чтобы сохранился действующий функционал, но еще маска подставлялась в зависимости от страны, которая загрузилась в поле `select` по умолчанию? Пример:  Раньше в `select` нужно было выбирать страну, сейчас страна грузится по умолчанию (в разных случаях разная) и при первой загрузке срабатывает маска для России, а потом уже при выборе все работает согласно вашего скрипта, но сейчас не всегда Россия загружается по умолчанию, поэтому возникла необходимость в жесткой привязке что выбрано в select такая и маска. Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: А что если девятки в коде, допустим Грузия или Узбекистан: 80: "+995(999) 999-999", //Georgia

Comment: @Семен , добавил вариант с использованием девятки в маске

Answer (score 3):

Получаем `value` значение с `<select>` и подставлять его в `.mask()`

```js
let numchange = $('#number_country'),
    input = $('#phone_1_field');

function ChangeMask(mask) {
  if($.isNumeric(mask)) {// Если получили число, то
      mask = '+'+mask+' (999) 999-9999';
      input.mask(mask); // Создаём маску
      input.attr('placeholder', mask.replace(/9/g, '_')); // Для красоты сделаем ещё и placeholder
    } else {
      input.unmask(); // Если не число то снимаем маску.
      input.attr('placeholder', 'Телефон');
    }
} ChangeMask(numchange.val()); // При первой загрузке выдаём маску

numchange.on('change', function() {
  ChangeMask($(this).val()); // Выдаём маску при изменении кода города
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

select,
input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.maskedinput@1.4.1/src/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select id="number_country">
    <option value="">-- Выберите Вашу страну --</option>
    <option value="374">Армения</option>
    <option value="375">Беларусь</option>
    <option value="7" selected>Российская Федерация</option>
    <option value="380">Украина</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div><input placeholder="Телефон" type="text"  id="phone_1_field" class="required"> </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Решение рабочее и очень изящное, но в моем частном случае, нельзя изменять файл в котором option имеет предустановленное значение value="220", value="176" и т.д. Возможно ли как-то увязать данное значение с кодом страны, к примеру если выбрано  `option value="220"` то в маске +380, если `option value="176"` то в маске +7 итд. Скрипт не сильно разрастется, т.к. стран подразумевается не более 15, я по примеру заведу / с масштабирую все условия в скрипте, если у меня будет пример хотя бы на 2-3 страны.